Attach with X32Dbg behaves strange
I am trying to attach to a debug protected 32bit Windows program with X32Dbg and in general the attach process works and the program still run smoothly.
However I CANNOT pause the program and check CPU state or step through assembler commands (but I can suspend and start the main thread and other depending threads without problems).
Also when I try to show or dump memory areas (like the program image located in RAM) these areas are completely filled with 0x00 bytes.
I tried Scylla without success. HyperHyde does not work because the program I want to debug detects when Windows (Win10 in my case) is in "testsigning mode" (which is necessary for HyperHide) and does not start at all.
Is there anybody who can help me?
